Speed up Websocket Connection
When I'm monitoring on Solana logs subscribe method it's actually has a delay of around 17 seconds to get the response.
await websocket.send(json.dumps({
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "logsSubscribe",
        "params": [
            {"mentions": [raydium_v4_amm]},
            {"commitment": "finalized"}
        ]
    }))

The moment the transaction has been finished is 15:33:36 but the moment data was received from the websocket is 15:33:53 which means 17s delay.
i need to know how to use geyser to monitor Logs subscribe on solana extremly fast,
is there anything more than this? i need to know,
i 've also tried

SHYFT
QUICKNODE
HELIUS

there is also a delay like this

Have you been using private RPCs? Free RPC are more likely to have delay on any request, when i was using  proivate Quicknode RPC i received responses almost immediately

which way you does compare it?

Its easy, private RPCs are paid ones, if you buy premium/private RPC you get your own endpoint which is not halted by other public users, many people use public RPCs and thats why they are slower in most cases

Just like you mentioned 17s delay, when i was using public RPCs i remember i had delays about 12-24seconds, when i switch to private ones i managed to get notification from chain within 3 seconds, and i was also using onAccountChange method to monitor wallet changes (token buys/sells) etc..and you have really strict restrictions when it comes to requests per second, public ones offer 5-15 RQ/s, if you get private ones you mostly have 50+rq/s depends on your package you buy
